# Remover índices do array

Tags: php, array

Como remover índices de um array?

Array original

```
["Torrada" => 4,"Cachorro quente" => 1]
```

para

```
[4,1]
```

Comment: Em *PHP* não seria: `["Torrada" => 4,"Cachorro quente" => 1]` ?

Comment: @NoobSaibot correto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php) retorna todos os valores de um array:

```
$Array = ["Torrada" => 4,"Cachorro quente" => 1];
$Valores = array_values($Array);
print_r($Valores);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1
)
```

#### Referência

- [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)

Comment: Ae deu certo noobsaibot

Comment: No caso erá somente informar `array_values($info['data']);`

Comment: era o print_r que tava acusando o erro... obrigado